# JComboBox, what listener when I need to catch a mouse click after a state (has not to be new) is selected?

Tags: swing, jcombobox

Can't use an `ItemListener` because my JComboBox items are generated dinamically so that would generate exceptions when the list is empty.
I need to catch basically the state after a mouse click event on an item (the problem with MouseListener is that it catches the event even when I open the list of items in the JComboBox).

Comment: A MouseListener is, most of the time, too low level. Always remember that you should be able to use swing components without a mouse, with the keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `ActionListener`.

See [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). Especially [Handling Events on a Combo Box](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners) section.

Comment: +1, although this is a more relevant link - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners

Comment: @little bunny foo foo Thanks! I missed that link in a hurry. I've added it.

Comment: look what I've found. This was the problem I was having: http://schinckel.net/2008/05/15/java-6-breaks-jcombobox-events/

Comment: @dierre I use java 1.6.0_25. I haven't noticed the issue described on that link.

Comment: combo's behaviour has changed erractitcally across versions: see f.i. http://wiki.java.net/twiki/bin/view/Javadesktop/SwingXComboBox and links there.